# How can I parse custom type in a digestive-functors form?

Tags: haskell, digestive-functors

I have no problems trying to parse built-in types in a digestive-functors form, e.g I have a Client type (generated by the persistent library) that references a Country ID (of Key Country type):

```
Client
  :: String
     -> String
     -> String
     -> Database.Persist.Class.Key Country
     -> Maybe Int
     -> Client
```

Then I define a clientForm value:

```
clientForm :: Monad m => Form String m Client                                                                           
clientForm = Client <$> "firstName" .: string Nothing                                                                   
                    <*> "lastName"  .: string Nothing                                                              
                    <*> "address"   .: string Nothing                                                              
                    <*> "country"   .: stringRead "Cannot parse country" Nothing                                   
                    <*> "age"       .: optionalStringRead "Cannot parse age" Nothing
```

Strangely, the clientForm when submitted (POST), cannot parse the country id field.
[image]

Is it wrong to use "stringRead" to parse "Key Country" type (which can be obtained from "toSqlKey int64")?

Comment: tbh: I don't know exactly how a Sql-Key looks like (it will be an instance of `Show` and `Read`) but based on what you see here it is not just an integer - easiest solution I can think of is that you just use `show` to print you one such key and have a look at it - it will most likely be some kind of GUID(?)

Comment: or you use [`fmap fromSqlKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.1.2/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:fromSqlKey) with what you have

Comment: @CarstenKönig after some digging, you are right, it's not directly an integer. CountryKey {unCountryKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 3}}. Do you know of any way to parse an Integer (presumably in the form it's given as a String) to CountryKey type?

Answer (score 1):

After some help from dmwit Freenode #haskell, the following will solve the problem:

```
clientForm :: Monad m => Form String m Client                                                                           
clientForm = Client <$> "firstName" .: string Nothing                                                                   
                <*> "lastName"  .: string Nothing                                                              
                <*> "address"   .: string Nothing                                                              
                <*> (toSqlKey <$> "country" .: stringRead "Cannot parse country id." Nothing)                                   
                <*> "age"       .: optionalStringRead "Cannot parse age" Nothing
```

I think the confusion came from the fact that "Key Country" type (a newtype) cannot be "read" directly from an integer...